# how to copy files from one docker service to another, inside of docker bash

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to copy a file from one docker-compose service to another while in the service's bash environment, but I cannot seem to figure out how to do it.

Can anybody provide me with an idea?

Here is the command I am attempting to run:

`(docker cp ../db_backups/latest.sqlc pgadmin_1:/var/lib/pgadmin/storage/mine/)`

The error is simply:

`bash: docker: command not found`

Comment: do you mean data from one docker container to another? They are kind of separated computers. Did you tried using sftp and the ip addresses of the docker containers?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do that by default. There are a few things you could do to enable that behavior.

The easiest solution is just to run `docker cp` on the host (`docker cp` from the first container to the host, then `docker cp` from the host to the second container).

If it all has to be done inside the container, the next easiest solution is probably to use a shared volume:

```
docker run -v shared:/shared --name containerA ...
docker run -v shared:/shared --name containerB ...
```

Then in `containerA` you can `cp ../db_backups/latest.sqlc /shared`, and in `containerB` you can `cp /shared/latest.sqlc /var/lib/pgadmin/storage/mine`.

This is a nice solution because it doesn't require installing anything inside the container.

Alternately, you could:

- Install the `docker` CLI inside each container, and mount the Docker socket inside each container. This would let you run your `docker cp` command, but it gives anything inside the container complete control of your host (because access to `docker` == `root` access).
- Run `sshd` in the target container, set up the necessary keys, and then use `scp` to copy things from the first container to the second container.